# Error during the running django project

Tags: django, python-3.x, pycharm

I'm running django project but i got this error. Can you help me with this problem?

```
"C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2017.2.2\bin\runnerw.exe" C:\Users\Jaloliddin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\python.exe E:/download/manage.py runserver 8000
    Unhandled exception in thread started by <function check_errors.<locals>.wrapper at 0x0368ED68>
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\Jaloliddin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django-1.11.5-py3.6.egg\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 228, in wrapper
        fn(*args, **kwargs)
      File "C:\Users\Jaloliddin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django-1.11.5-py3.6.egg\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 117, in inner_run
        autoreload.raise_last_exception()
      File "C:\Users\Jaloliddin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django-1.11.5-py3.6.egg\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 251, in raise_last_exception
        six.reraise(*_exception)
      File "C:\Users\Jaloliddin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django-1.11.5-py3.6.egg\django\utils\six.py", line 685, in reraise
        raise value.with_traceback(tb)
      File "C:\Users\Jaloliddin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django-1.11.5-py3.6.egg\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 228, in wrapper
        fn(*args, **kwargs)
      File "C:\Users\Jaloliddin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django-1.11.5-py3.6.egg\django\__init__.py", line 27, in setup
        apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
      File "C:\Users\Jaloliddin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django-1.11.5-py3.6.egg\django\apps\registry.py", line 85, in populate
        app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
      File "C:\Users\Jaloliddin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django-1.11.5-py3.6.egg\django\apps\config.py", line 120, in create
        mod = import_module(mod_path)
      File "C:\Users\Jaloliddin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
        return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 978, in _gcd_import
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 961, in _find_and_load
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 936, in _find_and_load_unlocked
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 205, in _call_with_frames_removed
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 978, in _gcd_import
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 961, in _find_and_load
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 948, in _find_and_load_unlocked
    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'blog'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you have in your settings.py, in apps, 'blog', which cannot be found. Doublecheck your settings and your path.